# arbitrary number of cpu's in a virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, grid

I'm planning to give a seminar / demonstration on the advantages of grid computing. As we don't have a physical grid (yet), I thought I would create a set of virtual machines, set up GridEngine and give a little demo with it.

To be realistic I would like to have 8 or 16 [virtual] core virtual machines. The problem is that neither VirtualBox nor VMWare player seems to allow setting the number of [virtual] cores to an arbitrary number. Is it a way to circumvent this limitation? Or, alternatively is it there a virtualization solution which makes this possible?

**SOLUTION**

In the meantime I've found **qemu**, an extremely versatile virtualization tool. Not only it can set the number of cores to anything between 1 and 255, but it can also use previously created VirtualBox disk images.

Starting an off-the-shelf virtual machine with 16 cores using a previously created VirtualBox disk image is as simple as:

`qemu -smp 16 disk.vdi`

Comment: Do you expect GridEngine to run faster on simulated virtual cores, or is that really just for demonstration purposes?

Comment: It would be solely for demonstration purposes.